# Recommended instance size for AD controller on AWS

Tags: active-directory, amazon-ec2

What is the recommended size of instance on AWS for Active Directory domain controllers? I have one controller, and another that joins for replication. Would 2 m1.small be sufficient?

Things we have running on the AWS domain:

- 2x instances of Dynamics CRM
- 2x pairs of Sql Server Always On Availability Group
- 8x windows IIS boxes communicating using WCF + Kerberos Authentication.
- ~4x more boxes running miscellaneous things.

We have a group of around 5 dev/ops who log in infrequently and 5x users for CRM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily get by with a m1.small for a normal size network, I think your network size should be fine with 2 m1.small instances.

DO NOT use a micro instance. Especially if you're also running DNS on the same machine. The micro instances are very different in the way they handle resources and if use them you can expect to have periods of time where your DNS or AD server is almost unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

As small as you can get. Heck, you can likely run ithem in a micro size, although the bootup will not be nice.... so small for all of them would be enough. They should settle below 700mb RAM usage. CPU basically flatlining ;)